# Job SSIS - Extract data from PostgreSQL to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, ssis, x86

I have some troubles to automatize a package SSIS with a job SQL Server.

I have to get some data from a DB PostgreSQL to a DB SQL Server. For that, I'm using an ODBC connector (downloaded from http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/msi/ and added using administrator console odbc in C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad.exe):

driver odbc:

[image]

odbcad:

[image]

To be able to run the SSIS package, I had to change debugging settings in SSDT to run the package in 32 bits mode :

[image]

So far, everything works fine, but when I'm trying to automatize it with a SQL Server job, the job fails. Yet, I specified to my job to run in 32 bits mode too:

[image]

Below, the errors I got (sorry it's french):

[image]

The most meaningful error is

> failed to call method acquireconnection to connection manager "PostgreSQL". Error code : 0xC0014009

I'm stuck & every related posts I found are solved using the checkbox "32 bits mode" checked on the job.

Comment: Did you create the  the odbc `DSN` under `User` or `System` also did you save the credentials in your DSN entry in odbc? Can you logon to the machine using the account SQL Agent is using? Once you have logged on check if you can see the `DSN` in ODBC.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Honestly, I don't know, how can I check if I created it in User or System ?
And how do you save the credentials in DSN entry ?
I will check if the account SQL Agent can see the DSN in ODBC, I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Thank's to M.Ali, I found the solution.

I just needed to add the DSN connection under **System** because the job SQL Agent is launch with another account than my current user.